# PHP - 2-ways binds two classes?

Tags: php, oop

For a project, I have a `class Member` and a `class Certificate`.

A member has a certificate (or not), and a certificate must be bound to a member.

Is there a way to access the certificate via `$member->certificate`, and a member via `$certificate->member` without doing an infinite loop?

Comment: Legit question, down-voters not commenting should be kicked in the nut5 ..

Comment: One way, don't require them in the constructors. Use setters for them. Use getters for properties, If you do what them as properties then make them private and use the 'magic' __get($name). Demonstration of it all: https://eval.in/639631.

Comment: Nice, thanks ! Gonna look at this

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since a member can exist without a certificate, you will have his constructor have a default certificate of null. Since a certificate **must** have a member with it, you will instruct this member to be passed during construction.

```
class Member
{
    public $certificate;

    public function __construct(Certificate $certificate = null)
    {
        $this->certificate = $certificate;
    }
}

class Certificate
{
    public $member;

    public function __construct(Member $member)
    {
        $this->member = $member;
        $member->certificate = $this;
    }
}


$member1 = new Member();
$certificate1 = new Certificate($member1);
```

---

By the way, that infinite-loop thing must've been a joke or something...

Comment: On your code, if I want an instance of Member with a Certificate, I need to instance the Certificate, which needs the Member and so on.

Comment: Oh god... No. Simply, No.